# Python - Como pegar a data da última atualização do Google Spreasheets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, google-sheets, google-api

Fala pessoal! 
Seguinte, precisava de fazer uma verificação se houve algum atualização no documento compartilhado do Google Spreasheets. Pensei em trazer esse campo: [image: Last edit by Google Spreadsheets] como uma data ou como um timestamp no python e verificar com o último salvo ou se a diferença fosse menor que um dia, mas não encontrei nada referente na documentação.

Um código de exemplo do que eu estava pensando em fazer:

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import gspread
import pandas as pd

def get_gsheet_table(url, sheet_name):

    # Autenticacao com conta Google a partir de um arquivo JSON na pasta 'credentials'
    scope = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('./credentials/get_sheet_table.json', scope)
    gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

    # Recebe os dados da planilha definida no paremetro
    wb = gc.open_by_url(url)
    sheet = wb.worksheet(sheet_name)
    
    #TO DO: verificar se teve atualização no último dia

    data = sheet.get_all_values()
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    df.columns = df.iloc[0]
    df = df.iloc[1:]
    return df
```

Se o código retornar que a planilha não foi atualizada ele poupa processos aqui. To procurando fazer desse jeito de pegar pela data do documento porque queria não precisar de fazer um planilha backup e comparar as duas.

Qualquer outra sugestão será bem vinda também

Comment: Após alguns dias sem resposta nesse tópico, abri uma pergunta na comunidade americana e tive uma resposta perfeita do usuário [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike). Ele me mostrou que tinha sim na documentação do Google Drive Api como olhar a data de modificações no arquivo através da Api [Revisions: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/list?apix_params=%7B%22fileId%22%3A%221ZFVXHSNZ_eOCaf0gKRvRrV4B8BoCVPqM4nB_P3H-xMI%22%7D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graças ao link da documentação passado pelo usuário [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike), consegui resolver o problema

Como ficou a parte do código:

```
import requests

revisions_uri = f'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{wb.id}/revisions'
    headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {credentials.get_access_token().access_token}'}
    response = requests.get(revisions_uri, headers=headers).json()
    print(response['revisions'][-1]['modifiedTime'])
```